# CSS centered div animates from wrong location

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to center a `div` in the middle of the window using CSS and then slide it to the left using the jQuery's `animate` function.  The CSS and animate function are working, however when the animation starts, the `div` jumps to the right and then animates from that location.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.  Notice that the red and yellow boxes should start at the same centered location, but the red box starts animating further right in the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/XMKCc/2/

To prove to myself that animate works correctly without a CSS centered div, I included two boxes centered using javascript in the same fiddle.  The pink box animates from the position that I would expect (directly over the purple one).

Is there anything I can do to get the CSS centered div working correctly with animate?

Code below

```
.centeredByCSS {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}

.centeredByJS {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:75px;
}

.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}

.red {
    background:red;
}

.purple {
    background:purple;
}

.pink {
    background:pink;
}

<div id="box1" class="centeredByCSS red">TEST1
</div>

<div id="box2" class="centeredByCSS yellow">TEST2
</div>

<div id="box3" class="centeredByJS purple">TEST3
</div>

<div id="box4" class="centeredByJS pink">TEST4
</div>

$(function(){
    //manually center the purple and pink boxes
    var location=(window.innerWidth/2)-parseInt($("#box3").css("width"))/2;
    $("#box3").css("left", location);
    $("#box4").css("left", location);

    // now animate two of the boxes 100 pixels left
    $("#box1").animate({left: "-100"}, 10000);
    $("#box4").animate({left: "-100"}, 10000);
})
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. What pink box?

Comment: @ShaanSingh The code in the fiddle and question were different, I updated the question

Comment: It seems to be working with the Javascript. Why do you have to use CSS to align?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your CSS markup to center it was incorrect. When you have `position:absolute;`, `margin:0 auto;` does not center your object. Instead, you will need to use `left:50%` and a negative `margin-left` of half the element's width, like so:

```
.centeredByCSS {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
    right:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Also, if you want to move an object left -100px from its current location you should use `-=`

```
$("#box1").animate({left: "-=100px"}, 10000);
$("#box4").animate({left: "-=100px"}, 10000);
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/XMKCc/4/)